# One or more plugins require a higher Android SDK version compileSdkVersion 33

Tags: android, flutter

Although the App works fine in emulator,I got this error during app build `Flutter build appbundle`.

> One or more plugins require a higher Android SDK version.
> Fix this issue by adding the following to H:\voo\android\app\build.gradle:
> android {
> compileSdkVersion 33
> ...
> }

The problem is that the current compileSdkVersion  in app\build.gradle is already 33 .

build.gradle:

```
android {

    compileSdkVersion 33

    lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds false
    }





    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.voo"
        minSdkVersion 20
        targetSdkVersion 33
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    signingConfigs {
        release {
            keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
            keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
            storeFile file(keystoreProperties['storeFile'])
            storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }
}
```

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Do you also need to adjust minSdkVersion? I see that it is set to 20

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue has been solved by doing the following:

1- Run `Pub outdated` command to list outdated packages,then i updated every outdated package to the latest release.

2-Edit Sdk version in android `build.gradle` to `7.0.4` to be compatible with `ext.kotlin_version = '1.7.21'`

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.4'
```

3-Make sure `org.jetbrains.kotlin` is `jdk7` in app `build.gradle`

```
  implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
```